# Uploading and Showing Images in mysql/phpmyadmin

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am currently trying to create a .php page to upload images to store in a table in phpmyadmin. Then to display them.

First things first, adding the image to the table within the database. Hierarchy in phpmyadmin is: localhost -> images -> Greeting_Cards.

Currently I am trying to insert into Greeting Cards table, as I will have multiple tables for multiple categories later and display them respectively.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>upload</title>
</head>

<body>

<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file_upload" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="upload" />
</form>


<?php
include '/var/db_file.php';
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  $conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root", $pass);
  mysql_select_db("images");
  
  /* Variable inits */
  $imageName = $imageData = $imageType = null;

  $imageName = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
  $imageData = mysql_real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]));
  $imageType = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES["image"]["type"]);

  if(substr($imageType,0,5) == "image"){
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO 'Greeting_Cards' VALUES('','$imageName','$imageData')");
    echo "Image Uploaded!";
  }
  else{
    echo "Has to be an image!";
  }
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

The uploaded image won't show up in the table. I am logging into the database correctly. The structure under the table "Greeting Cards" are: id(int11), name(varchar30), and image(blob). The only errors/warnings that shows up on the www.mydomainname.net/upload.php are:

> Notice: Undefined index: image in /var/www/html/upload.php on line 27
>
> Notice: Undefined index: image in /var/www/html/upload.php on line 28
>
> Warning: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty in
>   /var/www/html/upload.php on line 28
>
> Notice: Undefined index: image in /var/www/html/upload.php on line 29
>   Has to be an image!

To display the images, I have to get pass this step first. Will report back on this post if any update occurs.

**Fix 1: Wrong name:  Changed to name="image" to match with the php variable parameters.
Fix 2: Back ticks NOT single quotes for table name. Optional: Specify columns.**

Thanks in advance your help!

Comment: The input name is file_upload `<input type="file" name="file_upload" />` so used as `$_FILES["file_upload"]` instead of `$_FILES["image"]`

Comment: Oh my goodness...how did I overlook this. Thank you! The warnings and notices are gone. But do you happen to know where can I find the image in the table. Its not under "Browse" in phpmyadmin. Maybe its a setting I didn't tick in phpmyadmin?

Comment: Your query is wrong. you need to specify what columns to insert into.

Comment: It was the back ticks for table name, not single quotes. The columns are optional it appears( did both methods).

Comment: just on the sideline: In general i would recommend saving images to the filesystem and just saving a filename in the database. Once you are showing them in some kind of frontend you will have a hard time when a lot of users hit your site.

Comment: Haha yea, I've considered that also. But since it is really situation dependent, I have decided a blob would be best for now. But definitely if the time comes, I'll do what you recommended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fix 1: Wrong name: Changed to name="image" to match with the php variable parameters.**

**Fix 2: Back ticks NOT single quotes for table name. Optional: Specify columns.**

Answer (score 0):

uploading image

```
<!--?php
include("mysqlconnect.php");

    function GetImageExtension($imagetype)
     {
       if(empty($imagetype)) return false;
       switch($imagetype)
       {
           case 'image/bmp': return '.bmp';
           case 'image/gif': return '.gif';
           case 'image/jpeg': return '.jpg';
           case 'image/png': return '.png';
           default: return false;
       }
     }



if (!empty($_FILES["uploadedimage"]["name"])) {

    $file_name=$_FILES["uploadedimage"]["name"];
    $temp_name=$_FILES["uploadedimage"]["tmp_name"];
    $imgtype=$_FILES["uploadedimage"]["type"];
    $ext= GetImageExtension($imgtype);
    $imagename=date("d-m-Y")."-".time().$ext;
    $target_path = "images/".$imagename;


if(move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $target_path)) {

    $query_upload="INSERT into 'images_tbl' ('images_path','submission_date') VALUES 

('".$target_path."','".date("Y-m-d")."')";
    mysql_query($query_upload) or die("error in $query_upload == ----> ".mysql_error());  

}else{

   exit("Error While uploading image on the server");
} 

}

?>;
```

Displaying Images

```
<!--?php
include("mysqlconnect.php");

$select_query = "SELECT 'images_path' FROM  'images_tbl' ORDER by 'images_id' DESC";
$sql = mysql_query($select_query) or die(mysql_error());    
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql,MYSQL_BOTH)){

?-->

<table style="border-collapse: collapse; font: 12px Tahoma;" border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
<tbody><tr>
<td>

<img src="<?php echo $row[" images_path"];="" ?="">" alt="" />">

</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>

<!--?php
}
?-->
```